# How to Assign row numbers based on row values - Excel

Tags: excel, excel-formula

In the bellow excel data sheet, the values in the third column are manually entered. I would need a formula to automate this.

```
TYPE    | CATEGORY  | Expected_Value
fruits  | apple     | 1
fruits  | apple     | 2
fruits  | apple     | 3
fruits  | bananna   | 1
fruits  | bananna   | 2
fruits  | mango     | 1
fruits  | mango     | 2
fruits  | mango     | 3
fruits  | mango     | 4
fruits  | mango     | 5
```

*Expected_Value* represents the *n-th* duplicate of a given (TYPE, CATEGORY) couple.

Could someone help?

Comment: try `COUNTIF`. `=COUNTIF(B1:B18,A5)+1`

Answer (score 3):

You need to use `COUNTIF` with an absolute reference and a relative reference. If your Category column spanned from `B2` to `B12` you could use this:

```
=COUNTIF($B$2:B2,B2)
```

Comment: This is exactly what i was searching for. Thanks a ton.

Comment: No problem, if you're satisfied with this answer you can mark it as correct to show that the issue has been resolved.